# What punctuation do you use for strictly quoting a quote within a quote?

Tags: punctuation

What punctuation do you use for quoting a quote within a quote?

For example:

"He said, '**I like this**'"

How would you quote the bold portion?

(1) "'I like this'"

(2) "I like this"

Answer (score 2):

The typical rule is that quotes within standard double quotes get single quotation marks, so **"He said, 'I like this'"** would be correct. Some fonts make this more difficult to read, so it can be acceptable to add a space between the single quote and the double quote.

Depending on feasibility, a thoughtful writer might choose to rephrase their sentence or reselect their quote to avoid having too many punctuation marks together.

Here are some pages that talk about how to use quotes within quotes properly, and even quotes within quotes within quotes.

https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/quoting-a-question-within-a-question/

https://style.mla.org/quoted-material-in-quoted-material/